# Can't use constexpr static member function in a constant expression

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

I'm trying to play around with `constexpr` and `static_assert`. I actually need to check the length of a `constexpr` string, which is calculated by a dedicated function. Here is what I'm trying to run:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Test
{
    private :
        static constexpr char str[] = "abc";
        
        static int constexpr constStrLength(const char* str)
        {
            return *str ? 1 + constStrLength(str + 1) : 0;
        }

        static constexpr int length = constStrLength(str); // error here
        static_assert(length == 3, "error");
        
    public :
        static void f()
        {
            std::cout << length << std::endl;
        }
};
        
int main()
{
    Test::f();
}
```

And here is the error I get:

> error: 'static constexpr int Test::constStrLength(const char*)' called
> in a constant expression static constexpr int  len =
> constStrLength("length ");

What's the right way to achieve it?

Comment: Are you strings always initialized as `char str[] = "..."`? Because you could get the length simply as `sizeof(str)-1` in this form.

Comment: @kennytm: except, that doing so can produce wrong results. For example, `sizeof("abc\0def") - 1` yields `7` while the `constStrLength()` function would yield `3`.

Comment: My string is always defined like this, but indeed I need to prevent wrong behavior involving \0 character inside the string. But thanks for the tip ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `constexpr` function used as a `constexpr` function needs to be *defined* at the point of use. However, when you use `constStrLength()` to *define* `length` it is only *declared*: member function defined within the class definition are actually only *declared* within the class definition! Their definition becomes available right after the class definition, i.e., informally speaking right after the closing parenthesis.

The fix is to define `constStrLength()` prior to its use, e.g., as a non-member function or by defining it in a base class.

Comment: Oh, I thought that declaring the function as static would have defined it directly. Thanks for help, that solves my problem (I will use the base class hack)

Comment: @AntoineMorel: I think the relevant section is 9.2 [class.mem] paragraph 2: A class is considered a completely-defined object type (3.9) (or complete type) at the closing } of the _class-specifier_. Within the class _member-specification_, the class is regarded as complete within function bodies,
default arguments, _using-declarations_ introducing inheriting constructors (12.9), _exception-specifications_, and _brace-or-equal-initializers_ for non-static data members (including such things in nested classes). Otherwise
it is regarded as incomplete within its own class _member-specification_.